# Ask turtles to change colour when they go through a certain patch Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

When a turtle goes through a certain patch, it changes color and proceeds to move randomly with the new color. So I ask the turtles named 'yong' which are of a color yellow, if any of the 'yong' turtles goes through a patch in radius 2, it should change colour to green. My code runs without error but in the output, all the 'yong' turtles in yellow change colour to green which is not what I want.

```
to interact-turtles
 ask yong [
 if any? yong-on patches in-radius 2 [ set color green  ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are having the turtle ask about patches `in-radius`, which will put the origin of those patches wherever the turtle happens to be. Instead, you need the patches within 2 distance of the origin.

```
to interact-turtles
  let sink patches with [abs px-cor <= 2 and abs py-cor <= 2]
  ask yong-on sink [ set color green  ]
end
```

But if you want this sink area to be a permanent feature of the environment, you could use a variable to store it instead of creating it repeatedly. As a global variable:

```
globals [sink]

to setup
  ...
  set sink patches with [abs px-cor <= 2 and abs py-cor <= 2]
  ...
end
```

Then you can always `ask yong-on sink` to do things.

Or you can have a true/false (boolean) variable for each patch that says whether it is in the sink.

```
patches-own [sink?]

to setup
  ...
  ask patches [ set sink? if abs px-cor <= 2 and abs py-cor <= 2]
  ...
end
```

Then you can have constructions like `ask yong-on patches with [sink?]` to do things.

Comment: Thank you @JenB for you response. To clarify, I want any yong turtle that goes through the patch to change color from yellow to green. When I do this `ask yong [
  if any? other yong-on patches in-radius 2 [ set color green ]  ]` almost all the yong turtles turn green apart from two or three, which should the opposite. for example, I should have a only a few yong turtles turn to green not many.

Comment: You refer to "the patch". What patch do you mean?

Comment: The patch I mean is the area of the circle with the radius of 2 from the centre. I created it like this                                                                                                        
 `clear-all
  let sink-patch-radius 2
  let sink-centre patch 0 0 
  set sink-patches [patches in-radius sink-patch-radius] of sink-centre 
  ask sink-patches [ set pcolor red ]
  end `

Comment: That's your problem, you are asking for patches within 2 of the turtle doing the asking. I will revise